# Method that returns instance of subclass

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, methods, subclass

Here's a simple class and a derived class:

```
class A { public int val; }

class B : A { }
```

I'd like a method `Inc` which works on both `A` and `B` instances that returns a new instance with `val` incremented by 1.

One way to approach this is to define `Inc` as an extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static T Inc<T>(this T obj) where T : A, new()
    {
        return new T() { val = obj.val + 1 };
    }
}
```

This seems to work. In the following example, `a0.val` is *11* and `b0.val` is *21*.

```
var a = new A() { val = 10 };

var b = new B() { val = 20 };

var a0 = a.Inc();

var b0 = b.Inc();
```

My question is, is there a way to define `Inc` as a direct member of `A` and have it work as above?

If I define `A` like this:

```
class A 
{ 
    public int val;

    public T Inc<T>() where T : A, new()
    {
        return new T() { val = val + 1 };
    }
}
```

I then need to qualify the type when I call `Inc`:

```
var a = new A() { val = 10 };

var b = new B() { val = 20 };

var a0 = a.Inc<A>();

var b0 = b.Inc<B>();
```

Is there a way to go the member method route without having to qualify the type?

Comment: Do you expect `var b0` to be `B b0` or you are ok with `A b0`? If later clone solution be petseral is probably what you want. I don't think you can achieve reliable `B b0` (see  p.s.w.g comment to RagtimeWilly's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29158330/477420) ).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the result of `b.Inc()` should be of type `B`

Comment: Consider editing post with that important piece of info... And figure out what you expect from `A b = new B{val =20}; ??? b0 = b.Inc();`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible without implementing a `new` version of the method on each subclass, i.e,:

```
class A
{
    public int val;

    public virtual A Inc()
    {
        return new A { val = val + 1 };
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new B Inc()
    {
        return new B { val = val + 1 };
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use override in class B ?

Comment: It won't compile. You'll get a message saying 'cannot change return type when overriding'

Comment: It was ugly initially, now it's even worse.

Comment: @zerkms I never said it was pretty! Do you know another way to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: @RagtimeWilly nope :-) I personally would reconsider the whole solution, since the current attempt is broken by design.

Comment: Also note that with this solution, calling `Inc` from a variable of type `A` will call the version defined in `A` regardless of the underlying type. E.g. in `var a = (A)new B(); var a0 = a.Inc();`, `a` will actually be an instance of `B`, but `a0` will be an instance of `A`. (This same caveat applies to the original solution using extension methods, too)

Answer (score 2):

So, you practically want to create clone of object with different value for some field:

```
class A {
    public int val;
    protected virtual A CloneInternal() {
        return (A)MemberwiseClone();
    }
    public A Inc() {
        A a=CloneInternal();
        ++a.val;
        return a;
    }
}
class B:A {
    public new B Inc() {
        return (B)base.Inc();
    }
}
static void Main() {
    A a=new B();
    a=a.Inc();
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    abstract class Base
    {
        public int val { get; set; }

        public virtual Base Inc() { return null; }
    }

    class A : Base
    {

        public override Base Inc()
        {
            return new A { val = val + 1 };
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override Base Inc()
        {
            return new B { val = val + 2 };
        }
    }
```

Maybe using a abstract base class is better....

```
Base bClass = new B();
B bInc = bClass.Inc() as B;
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither I don't think it's possible. You should provide a hint in order to make compiler guesses proper type for `T`.

You might try with static method:

```
public static T Inc<T>(T source) where T : A, new()
{
   return new T() { val = source.val + 1 };
}
```

Then,

```
var b = new B { val = 20 };
var b0 = A.Inc(b);
```

But it's not an answer since you wanted a member method. I would rather go with extensions method.

Answer (score 1):

One more way

```
interface IInc
{
    int val { get; set; }

    IInc GetNew();

}

class A : IInc
{
    public int val
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual IInc GetNew()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public IInc Inc()
    {
        var newObj = GetNew();
        newObj.val++;

        return newObj;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override IInc GetNew()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

and use like

```
 var a = new A() { val = 10 };
 var b = new B() { val = 20 };
 var a0 = a.Inc();
 var b0 = b.Inc();
 Console.WriteLine(a0.val);
 Console.WriteLine(b0.val);
```